# Do documents in Danish need to be translated for UK standard visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, translations

So I am applying for a visa for my mom so that she can visit family in the UK. We live in Denmark. The gov.uk website states that all documents that are not in English or Welsh must be translated (no mention of the translations being certified). I was wondering whether I could translate the documents myself since I am fluent in both: Danish and English. Or could I ask a friend to translate documents for me (I think maybe the immigration office would mind if I translate the documents myself)? Also, I heard from a few friends that you don't need to translate documents that are in Danish. So what is the truth in all of this? Should I get documents like bank statements (which are pretty self explanatory) translated by a certified translators (who are crazy expensive in DK)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should refer to the detailed guidance in https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

“If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office. Each translated document must contain:

- confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original document
- the date of the translation
- the translator’s full name and signature
- the translator’s contact details”

AFAIK, it is not typically necessary to get bank statements translated, given that the information provided is usually self-explanatory - a debit/credit is a debit/credit in any language.

Comment: My mother in law was refused a UK visa some years ago and among the reasons given was the failure to translate her bank statements.

Comment: Does each paper in the document need a separate stamp of the certified translator or would a single stamp be okay for the entire bundle? Since, 1 stamp costs 250 DKK (stupid expensive for a stamp).

Comment: @phoog where was ur mother in law applying from?

Comment: @SelenaCarlos Sarajevo. The statements were written in Bosnian, in the Latin alphabet.  It's probably not necessary for the translation to be certified.  Which visa are you applying for?

Comment: @phoog I applied for a standard visitor visa for my momma. Your assumption that the translations need not be certified may be correct, since, the gov.uk website does not explicitly state that the translators need to be certified. However, I've read other forums and sources which point towards the importance of a certified translation. What a bummer!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your mother has a Danish passport you shouldn't need a Visa at all. See https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/denmark

Comment: Where did you get that OP and the mother are Danish citizens? Plenty of people live in other countries than where they have their passports from.